# column packed save space in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Based on this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/SFN4maoWkYA?t=1090) we can see that column alignment of the same integer size will save space. That's very good. But I'm still confused. Is it based on data type alignment or data type size?  I believe in that based on data type size, rather than data type.

Answer (score 1):

The length of a data type (column `typlen` in `pg_type`) determines how much space a value will use, but it has nothing to do with padding or wasted space between columns owing to alignment (column `typalign`).

You only waste space if the next column has a bigger alignment than the current one, and padding bytes are needed to fill up the space in between.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   x boolean NOT NULL,
   y boolean NOT NULL,
   z integer NOT NULL
);
```

Each `boolean` has an alignment and length of 1 byte, and `integer` has an alignment of 4 bytes. So the bytes will look like this:

```
┌──────────────┐
│       x      │
├──────────────┤
│       y      │
├──────────────┤
│ padding byte │
├──────────────┤
│ padding byte │
├──────────────┤
│       z      │
├──────────────┤
│       z      │
├──────────────┤
│       z      │
├──────────────┤
│       z      │
└──────────────┘
```

The first column starts at an offset that is maximally aligned (that is, the address is divisible by eight). Column `z` must start at an address that is divisible by 4, so two padding nytes are necessary.

Comment: Still confused. So why in the case:  next column has a bigger alignment than the current one will need padding?

Comment: I have added some more explanation.